# How make .htaccess get all string after query string

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have link:

> localhost/page/go/abc.html?var1=xxxx&var2=xxxx&var3=xxxx

and [.htaccess] is

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page/go.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it just return "**go/abc.html**" . i want get all such as "**abc.html?var1=xxxx&var2=xxxx&var3=xxxx**".

I'm newbie with .htaccess :(

Please help me.

Thanks for read and replay.

Comment: Check this one [An In-Depth Guide to mod_rewrite for Apache](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: `print_r ($_GET);` you will get all others like that `Array ( [q] => go.php/abc.html [var1] => xxxx [var2] => xxxx [var3] => xxxx )`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will read guid above for learn more .htaccess. And try the way you suggest.
I think haven't way to add all $_GET value in one with .htaccess ($_GET['q'] => abc.html?var1=xxxx&var2=xxxx&var3=xxxx" )